# How to read clipboard text in a java class that is stored in an oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have a Java class that reads text from the clipboard stored in an oracle database, when I try to execute the function that uses that class i get the following error.

```
select texttransfer
from dual;
```

> ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
>   oracle.aurora.awt.UnsupportedOperation: GUI not supported.

here is the class code:

```
public String readClipboard() throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException
{
     String text = "";
     Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
     Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(clipboard);
     text = (String)(contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));    

   return text;
}

public static String world()
{
    return "Hello world";
}
```

function code:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION TextTransfer RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'TextTransfer.readClipboard() return java.lang.String';
```

However, when I call the method world() it executes perfect.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as the Exception `oracle.aurora.awt.UnsupportedOperation: GUI not supported` already says. In Oracle you have no windowing system so you canno access the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks Uwe for your quick reply, is there a possible of doing the same thing but using Plsql?

Comment: @Sabe I don't think that it is possible to access the systems clipboard from the database. This would be a security breach. Also I think most Db servers are running on computers which do not have a clipboard at all.

Answer (score 1):

Java stored procedures (as well as pl/sql procedures) are executed on server side and has no access to GUI of client (including clipboard, screen, audio system, etc.).  Are you really want to read clipboard of server OS?

Answer (score 0):

The following is an extract from [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96659/02_load.htm).

`Oracle-specific Peer implementation that throws an exception, 
oracle.aurora.awt.UnsupportedOperation, if you execute Java code on the Oracle9i server that attempts to materialize a user interface.`

`Oracle9i's lack of support for materializing user interfaces in the server means that we do not pass the Java 2 Compatibility Kit tests for java.awt, java.awt.manual, and java.applet`